# Wordpress 404 page on Angular Application

Tags: angular, wordpress, angular-routing

I'm running an angular application in separate directory on server/domain that is hosting Wordpress website, when I refresh or directly try to access the application component path https://aplos.ca/calculatewebsitecost/first then Wordpress 404 page comes up but accessing the angular application main path works fine. https://aplos.ca/calculatewebsitecost/

I tried setting 404 redirect in angular application but that doesn't work because WordPress 404 page is overwriting angular application 404 redirect.

I want to redirect components path traffic to https://aplos.ca/calculatewebsitecost/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing since it's a wordpress website you are hosting it on an apache server, so what you need to do is to handle the .htaccess file in a way that pleases angular. which is some exception in the main .htaccess to skip your angular routes from roles written for wordpress pages and some redirecting roles to take your routes to the index.html of the angular app so the angular could handle them for you
[here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/270249/htaccess-for-angular-app-in-a-subfolder) is a similar case which is answered, hope you find it helpfull

Comment: Thank you @AminSetayeshfar. creating and adding rule for a separate .htaccess file in angular application folder fixed the issue.